# reading in and merging multiple .las in a pdal pipeline file

Tags: pipeline, pdal

I can read in and output single .las files in a pipeline file.

How do I read in two .las files, merge them, then apply the filter and output based on the below example?

```
{
  "pipeline":[
    {
      "type":"readers.las",
      "filename":"E:\\offload\\3dspatial\\processed\\99.526\\201406071257\\201406071257.las",
      "spatialreference":"EPSG:32635"
    },
    {
      "type":"filters.chipper",
      "capacity":600
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.pgpointcloud",
      "connection":"host='localhost' dbname='db' user='user' password='pw'",
      "schema":"pointcloud_99_526",
      "table":"pc_201406071257",
      "compression":"dimensional",
      "srid":"32635"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just testing it.

```
{
  "pipeline":[
    {
      "type":"readers.las",
      "filename":"E:\\offload\\3dspatial\\processed\\99.526\\201607150650\\201607150650.las",
      "spatialreference":"EPSG:32635",
"tag":"A"
    },

    {
      "type":"readers.las",
      "filename":"E:\\offload\\3dspatial\\processed\\99.526\\201607140910\\201607140910.las",
      "spatialreference":"EPSG:32635",
"tag":"B"
    },


        {
            "type":"filters.merge",
            "tag":"merged",
            "inputs":[
                "A",
                "B"
            ]
        },


    {
      "type":"filters.chipper",
      "capacity":600
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.pgpointcloud",
      "connection":<info>,
      "schema":"pointcloud_99_526",
      "table":"pc_merge_201607150650_201607140910",
      "compression":"dimensional",
      "srid":"32635"
    }
  ]
}
```